# Google Apps Script: Use getFolderById for multiple variables depending on value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I think I have a very simple issue with Google Apps Script, but I already tried to google the solution for 1.5hrs without success. I guess I search for the wrong terms.

**Here my code:**

```
function folderLocations(){
  var folder = {
    Michael: '1bz9wIBRcRN2V-xxxxxxxxxx',
    Chris: '1AEKHiI8iZKjHs-xxxxxxxxxx',
    Steve: '1TD8iwjcbR7K5dN-xxxxxxxxxx',
  };
  return folder;
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {

  //ID of Google Docs Template, what sheet to use + save all values as 2D array
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxx_XznDn-i0WVtIM');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Current Overview');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    
    //Destination folder ID (can differ from each person)
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations().Chris);

    // Set custom file name and create file
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[15]} - ${row[3]} Quarterly Review` , destinationFolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    
    // Replace placeholders with real values
    body.replaceText('%NAME%', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('%QUARTER%', row[15]);
    body.replaceText('%ANSWER_1%', row[16]);
    body.replaceText('%ANSWER_2%', row[17]);
    [...]
    doc.saveAndClose();
    
  })
}
```

All working fine! BUT: What I want is to "dynamically" change the folder, depending on the value of a cell. It's not always "Chris"...:

```
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations().Chris);
```

E.g.: If row[4] == Michael, then use the folder ID of "Michael". Somehow I can't get it to work to be "dynamically".

I already tried all this, none working:

```
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations().row[4]);
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations(row[4]));
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations().`${row[4]}`);
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations().toString(row[4]));
etc.
```

I know what I try to do here is embarrassing. But I am normally not a developer and nobody at my company is familiar with Google Apps Script. That's the last bit I am missing, rest I put together myself using Google.

Thank you SOO much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a function. Just an object is enough:

```js
const folderLocations = {
    Michael: '1bz9wIBRcRN2V-xxxxxxxxxx',
    Chris: '1AEKHiI8iZKjHs-xxxxxxxxxx',
    Steve: '1TD8iwjcbR7K5dN-xxxxxxxxxx',
};

var id = folderLocations['Chris'];

console.log(id); // 1AEKHiI8iZKjHs-xxxxxxxxxx
```

```
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations[row[4]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick :

```
function folderLocations(person){
  var folder = {
    Michael: '1bz9wIBRcRN2V-xxxxxxxxxx',
    Chris: '1AEKHiI8iZKjHs-xxxxxxxxxx',
    Steve: '1TD8iwjcbR7K5dN-xxxxxxxxxx',
  };
  return folder[person];
}
```

...further below:

```
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderLocations(row[4]));
```